# How to set a separate value for each category to open related categories in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello respected developers! I am trying to set separate category value for each category but now when I click on Pizza category it shows pizza, and when I click on other categories like Sandwich, Burger or anything else. it show the same value as it was designed in a widget. How to set category value for each category screen to have its own and related value. Please help me. here is a portion of my code that need to be fixed I can do it with a hard code but if I have more than 10 categories my code will be too long. Thank you very much and I really appreciate your help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zar/screen/categories.dart';

class TopCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const TopCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TopCard> createState() => _TopCardState();
}

// TOP CARD CLASS STARTS HERE
class CardItem {
  final String urlImage;
  final String title;
  final String subTitle;

  const CardItem({
    required this.urlImage,
    required this.title,
    required this.subTitle,
  });
}

// TOP CARD WIDGETS STARTS HERE
Widget topCard({
  required CardItem item,
  required BuildContext context,
}) =>
    Container(
      width: 150,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 2 / 2,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Material(
                  child: Ink.image(
                    image: NetworkImage(item.urlImage),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Categories(
                            item: item,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 4),
          Text(
            item.title,
            style: const TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xff5e35b1),
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text(
            item.subTitle,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

class _TopCardState extends State<TopCard> {
// TOP CARD LIST VIEW STARTS HERE
  List<CardItem> items = const [
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542834369-f10ebf06d3e0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80',
      title: 'PIZZA',
      subTitle: '\$20',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621852004158-f3bc188ace2d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80',
      title: 'SANDWICH',
      subTitle: '\$7.99',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534938665420-4193effeacc4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=871&q=80',
      title: 'FRIES',
      subTitle: '\$2.99',
    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage:
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585238341710-4d3ff484184d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=804&q=80',
      title: 'BURGER',
      subTitle: '\$5.99',
    ),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      height: 150,
      child: ListView.separated(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 4,
        separatorBuilder: (constext, _) => const SizedBox(width: 16),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => topCard(
          context: context,
          item: items[index],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my home screen category
[image]

This is my Category screen that shows Pizza categories.
[image]

And again this is my Category screen that shows the same Pizza categories. And I want this to be different.
[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      height: 150,
      child: ListView.separated(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 4,
        separatorBuilder: (constext, _) => const SizedBox(width: 16),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => topCard(
          context: context,
          item: items[index],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is my category screen code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zar/widgets/top_card.dart';

class Categories extends StatelessWidget {
  final CardItem item;
  const Categories({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(item.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 350,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: const Color(0xff673ab7),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                  child: Image.network(item.urlImage),
                ),
                Text(
                  item.title,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: height * 0.01,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 167,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    child: Material(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        height: 300,
                        width: width * 0.9,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: const Color(0xff5e35b1).withOpacity(0.3),
                              blurRadius: 6.0,
                              offset: const Offset(4, 8),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 6,
                    left: 5,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 10.0,
                      shadowColor: const Color(0xff5e35b1).withOpacity(0.3),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            image: const DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625395005224-0fce68a3cdc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=580&q=80"),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 15,
                    left: 180,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width: 180,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Pizza",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff5e35b1),
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Italian Chees and Beef",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(
                            color: Color(0xff5e35b1),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 120,
                    left: 180,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Rating",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text("4.5"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 120,
                    left: 350,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Price",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text("\$20"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: height * 0.01,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 167,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    child: Material(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        height: 300,
                        width: width * 0.9,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: const Color(0xff5e35b1).withOpacity(0.3),
                              blurRadius: 6.0,
                              offset: const Offset(4, 8),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 6,
                    left: 5,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 10.0,
                      shadowColor: const Color(0xff5e35b1).withOpacity(0.3),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            image: const DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606502281004-f86cf1282af5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=580&q=80"),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 15,
                    left: 180,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width: 180,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Special Mini Pizza",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff5e35b1),
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "American Pizza",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(
                            color: Color(0xff5e35b1),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 120,
                    left: 180,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Rating",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text("4.5"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 120,
                    left: 350,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Price",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text("\$9.99"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: height * 0.01,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 167,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    child: Material(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        height: 300,
                        width: width * 0.9,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: const Color(0xff5e35b1).withOpacity(0.3),
                              blurRadius: 6.0,
                              offset: const Offset(4, 8),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 6,
                    left: 5,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 10.0,
                      shadowColor: const Color(0xff5e35b1).withOpacity(0.3),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            image: const DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628840042765-356cda07504e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=580&q=80"),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 15,
                    left: 180,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width: 180,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Paparoni Pizza",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff5e35b1),
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Maxcan Pizza",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(
                            color: Color(0xff5e35b1),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 120,
                    left: 180,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Rating",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text("4.5"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 120,
                    left: 350,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Price",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text("\$17.50"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: height * 0.01,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 167,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    child: Material(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        height: 300,
                        width: width * 0.9,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: const Color(0xff5e35b1).withOpacity(0.3),
                              blurRadius: 6.0,
                              offset: const Offset(4, 8),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 6,
                    left: 5,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 10.0,
                      shadowColor: const Color(0xff5e35b1).withOpacity(0.3),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            image: const DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585828922344-85c9daa264b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=640&q=80"),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 15,
                    left: 180,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 150,
                      width: 180,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Mashroom Pizza",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff5e35b1),
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "European Pizza",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Divider(
                            color: Color(0xff5e35b1),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 120,
                    left: 180,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Rating",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text("4.5"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 120,
                    left: 350,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Price",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text("\$15.99"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my home screen code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zar/widgets/top_card.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: const [
            TopCard(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code where you use the `topCard` method?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. But we also need to see your `Categories` widget code as this is where the list is displayed as I understood. So you home page list and your categories list code are needed for me to see the full picture

Comment: You want to show a list of available items for the selected category on category page or just single product?

Comment: I just added some more codes.

Comment: Hello Diwyansh, Yes I want to show a list of available items for selected category. Like Pizza category should have it's own category, Sandwich should have it's own category and Burger should have it's own category.